# Spacing between collectionview columns differ on screen sizes iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating a `UICollectionView` of Images. I do not want any spacing between the cells. To get this I do the following :-

```
public override nfloat GetMinimumInteritemSpacingForSection(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
{
        return 0;
}

public override nfloat GetMinimumLineSpacingForSection(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
{
        return 0;
}

public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
       if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height > 567)
        {
            return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(100, 100);
        }
        else
        {
            return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(80, 80);
        }
}

public override UIEdgeInsets GetInsetForSection(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, nint section)
{
    return new UIEdgeInsets(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

With this code I the cells looks fine on a iPhone 5S screen but when I test it on a iPhone 6 on wards the cells have too much spacing between them like below:

[image: iPhone 5s]

[image: iPhone 6]

How can I solve this and achieve no space at all between the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all device have 4 cells in row then set cell size on the basis of device width.

```
public override CoreGraphics.CGSize GetSizeForItem(UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) {

   CoreGraphics.CGFloat width = (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 4)
   return new CoreGraphics.CGSize(width, width);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was  the exact problem :)

Comment: Welcome mate, Glad it helped :)